# Style for if-else no-ops in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I've got a test for whether I'm going to perform a particular action, and I want to log if don't do it. The don't-do-it branch just contains a nil-returning log operation.

I often find myself writing something like:

```
(if-not (need-to-do-it?)
  (log "Don't need to do it")
  (do
    (log "Doing it")
    (do-something)))
```

The weakness of this is the similar to the classic C `if` bug. Someone could remove the `log` and completely change the semantics of the program (although that would cause a syntax error).

So I could solve it by including a 'block' with an explicit `nil` to indicate the no-op. But that looks messy.

```
(if-not (need-to-do-it?)
  (do
    (log "Don't need to do it")
    nil)
  (do
    (log "Doing it")
    (do-something)))
```

The alternative is this, which is clearer but requires an extra let-binding...

```
(let [need-to (need-to-do-it?)]
  (when-not need-to
    (log "Don't need to do it"))

  (when need-to
    (log "Doing it")
    (do-something)))
```

But it's more verbose.

Is there a common pattern for expressing this kind of logging no-op in an if branch or similar side-effect functions in an `if` branch? Explaining with a comment each time isn't great.

Comment: You could just flip it to `if-not` and if someone removes the log statement the behavior is unchanged

Comment: Oops. Long day. Fixed.

Comment: May wish to clarify the title to "noops" or "no-ops"

Answer (score 1):

Among your examples, your first example is IMO the most idiomatic and simple.  Your second example is needlessly complex and ugly, and the third example leaves the reader wondering, "why use `when` and `when-not`, instead of just `if`?"

Since there are no curly braces to deal with, and due to clojure's much simpler syntax than other languages (i.e., 95% of clojure forms are `(function args)`, there's little danger of someone inadvertently removing the "then" portion of an `if` in clojure.  If they do, it will be a nice lesson learned for them, and attempting to guard against this will result in code that is less readable to the vast majority of the clojure population (your 2nd and 3rd examples), in order to save the tiny minority from themselves.

As an aside, when it comes to cross-cutting concerns like logging, consider using the [Robert Hook library](https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke).  It's tiny, easy to use, and is a great example of using aspect-oriented programming priciples: you won't pollute your code to accommodate things which are vital, but have nothing to do with your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think your number 1 concern should be making your code as clear as
possible. It is a mistake to be concerned about types of bugs from
different languages - especially languages which differ so much or to worry
about someone else modifying the code and accidentally changing the semantics of
your program (this is what tests are for). I would also be wary about logging
too much. This is an error I've seen often.

No matter what language you are using, statements to log activity tend to
distract from what the code is really doing. The developer often believes they
are making things clearer. However, in reality, they are just creating
distractions which obscure the underlying algorithm.

If you do too much logging all that happens is you generate lots of log output
which nobody ever looks at. The reality is logs only get looked at when
something is wrong or to verify some critical action has occurred. Keep your
logging to a minimum. It is generally a *code smell* to log doing and not doing
something unless your doing it temporarily during development or debugging
processes.

Rather than log decisions, log actions. An absence of an expected log message
can tell you as much as a message that says nothing happened. If it is important
to know if an action took place, log that action and leave it at that. Don't
also log that the action did not occur. If it is important to know that an
action did not occur, log that and don't bother logging the action when it does
occur.

Tie your logging to the action. If you need to log that a function was called,
then put that bit of logging inside the action itself rather than
separately. This will prevent misleading logging where someone has modified the
code and removed the log message, giving the false belief the action did not
occur when it did.

With your examples, I would either do

```
(when need-to-do-it?
  (do-something)) ;; do-something can log if necessary
```

or

```
(if need-to-do-it?
  (do-something) ;; which itself may log what it does
  (log "Not doing it"))
```

I prefer the *if* over *if-not* because then the focus is on the algorithm. With
the *if-not* the focus is on the logging and not on what the code is actually
meant to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your second solution is the cleanest and most intuitive. Here, being explicit helps with understanding. It's also a easy pattern to spot, with the nesting lined up nicely.

In the third solution, you're relying on `when` returning `nil`, just as you are relying on `log` to return `nil` in the first solution. The third solution also has the same issue as the first: the semantics can accidentally be changed because the "if/else" is implicit.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - I'm not relying on log to return nil, I just don't care about the value. The `nil` in the second example might as well have been `:ignore`.

Comment: Regardless, in the first example you're returning whatever `log` returns.

Comment: True. The whole function is a side-effect-only.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with the first form 95% of the time.  After all, if someone thinks they can randomly delete lines from a program and not change the behavior, there is not much you can do to defend against that.

I do think clarity is often aided by being extra explicit, so on occasion I might lean toward the third form.  I don't see the middle version adding much value in this case.

Since Clojure already explicitly delimits the beginning & end of every expression in `(...)`, there is not really the equivalent the C bug of having or not having a single line wrapped in `{...}`.  Indeed, the C version looks like:

```
if need-to-do-it() {
  log("Don't need to do it")
} else {
  log("Doing it")
  do-something()
}
```

vs

```
if need-to-do-it() {
  log("Doing it")
  do-something()
}
```

In Clojure, deleting half of the clauses in an `if` expression is an equally major change as deleting half of the blocks in an `if-else` statement in C.